# Are there any haar cascades for detecting left ear and right ear in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I wanna detect left ears and right ears separately using OpenCV and python. I went into the data folder of opencv module and it showed all the haarcascades but there were none on ears. Are there any external haar cascades that I need to install for ears?
*This is the screen shot of the opencv data folder. It contains all of my haar cascades.*
[image: the screen shot of the folder]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using cascade.XML in the link below

https://github.com/shivangbansal/Haar-Cascade-Ear-Training/tree/master/classifier_20_set1_HAAR

Place it in the same folder with your Python script and try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ear_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
  ret, img = cap.read()


  gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ear = ear_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)


  for (x,y,w,h) in ear:
      cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 3)

  cv2.imshow('img',img)
  k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
  if k == 27:
      break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Otherwise you can create your own Haar cascades.

https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/

Comment: Wait. So you are telling me I can make my own haar cascades. I will definitely check them out. Thanks. I will accept your answer if it works

Comment: Umm. Is it just like using other haar cascades or do we need to do some extra code or something? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Creating Haar cascades is not an easy task. You have to collect and crop many images of the object and it takes long processing time to create.

Comment: Ok, I will use the already made one. But is the code same for the haar cascade? Is it same as the other haar cascades?

Comment: Testing those Haar cascades they seem to be of the old format so they need to be converted.

Comment: What do you mean by old formats? Do they work now in python 3.7? Do you know how to use them? If you know can you pls show me the code? (I know I am asking a lot of questions but I am sorry, I'm new)

Comment: The ones I gave you earlier are for old version of Opencv and are not working. I have changed the link try the new cascade, it works but it combines both left and right ears.